# Emulated eeprom in C8051F380 Silabs controllef

Tags: c51

In my project on the C8051F380 controller, it is necessary to save parameters after shutdown,
I am, as in the usual case, decided to use emulated EEPROM
But unfortunately, I couldn't find a detailed explanation on this topic,
Yes, there are some application notes, but there is no explanation of how to change the linker file.
I would like to receive a project with an example or application notes.

Advanced Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.